# The inclusion $N \hookrightarrow M$ defines a natural morphism $\mathcal{A}^*_{cpt}(N) \rightarrow \mathcal{A}^*_{cpt}(M)$ , what is it?

Tags: differential-geometry

In some lecture notes that I'm reading I found the following statement:

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. The inclusion $N \hookrightarrow M$ of an open subset defines a natural morphism $\mathcal{A}^*_{cpt}(N) \rightarrow \mathcal{A}^*_{cpt}(M)$ between the differential forms with compact support.

I Know that in general if $f : M \rightarrow N$ is smooth map between two manifolds we can define a map (The pullback) $f^*:\mathcal{A}^*(N) \rightarrow \mathcal{A}^*(M) $, but how can we define a map from $\mathcal{A}^*(M)$ to $\mathcal{A}^*(N)$ ?

Comment: The important property here is that the inclusion $\iota: N\hookrightarrow M$ is of an open set. This means that we have an isomorphism $A^*(N)\to A^*(\iota(N))$ given by the pushforward of forms. A form $\alpha$ with compact support in $\iota(N)$ can be extended to a form with compact support on $M$ by $\tilde{\alpha}\vert_{M-\iota(N)}=0, \tilde{\alpha}\vert_{\iota(N)}=\alpha$.

Comment: I understand, thanks a lot @J.V.Gaiter!